# Calculate energy to reverberation ratio in python

Tags: scipy, signal-processing, fft

Hi I am very new to signal processing and I am trying out a research paper. Here is a formula i need help with

std[ f1,f2][H( f )] = E[ f1,f2][H2( f )^2]- E^2[ f1,f2][H( f )]

where H( f ) denotes the Fourier transform of the RIR and
E[ f1,f2][] denotes taking empirical expectation over the frequency
band ranging from f1 to f2.

I have got the fourier transform and hence the magnitudes for each frequency. But dont to how to get expected frequency over a frequence band

Here is the paper http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jinming/papers/soundloc.pdf

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

In this context "empirical expectation over the frequency band" simply means an average of the argument from frequencies f1 up to f2. Frequencies will be obviously defined as boundaries of octaves or 1/3 octaves. Then simply take the argument and calculate its mean.